# Inverse of $y=\frac{1}{27}(x^5+2x^3)$?

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

Is it possible to find the inverse of a function such as $y=\frac{1}{27}(x^5+2x^3)$? This question was posed to me by an AP Calculus AB student. The function seems to be $1$-to-$1$ and have an inverse. However, I don't know a way to solve it. Symbolab doesn't seem to know either. The student was recalling the question from memory so I'm not $100\%$ sure this was the exact question. He also mentioned that a piece of information, $a=7$, might be a part of it. He was also under the impression that the question had to do with derivatives. Thoughts?

Comment: This is, as you suspected, way too little information to go off of. Most likely he was asked to compute the derivative of the inverse at some point, in which case the inverse is never needed to be calculated explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the vague question, but I think I've figured out what's going on here. Looking at the graph of any function with it's inverse, it's clear that if the slope of the tangent line at point $(a,b)$ is $m$, then the slope of the tangent line of the inverse function at point $(b,a)$ is $1/m$.
[image]

In this case, the derivative function would be $y'=\frac{1}{27}(5x^4+6x^2)$ and $y'(7)$ would be $\frac{12299}{27}$. The $b$ value would be $\frac{1}{27}((7)^5+2(7)^3)=\frac{5138}{9}$ and therefore $(y^{-1})'(\frac{5138}{9})=\frac{1}{\frac{12299}{27}}=\frac{27}{12299}$.

Answer (score 2):

While the function is indeed one-to-one, it is impossible in general to find an analytic expression for $x$ even at $y=1$ – the polynomial that has to be solved in that case, $x^5+2x^3-27$, has Galois group $S_5$.

Nevertheless, since the function is monotone and odd, Newton's method works very well to obtain a numerical result.